# What is doing $.unique() function in jQuery 1.4.2?

Tags: jquery

I've got a string with *no* spaces with ',' and duplicate entries. Why jQuery do not removing this?
`var arr = $.unique(data.split(','));`

Comment: Please provide a full code sample and use professional language.

Comment: Lol? I've posted it. I've got string like var data = "omg,lol,omg".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're not using the right function for this.

From the [jQuery documentation on `$.unique`:](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/)

> Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array) contains some approaches for a generic array_unique solution.

Answer (score 1):

[`$.unique()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) isn't assured to work on arrays of strings, it has a specific purpose, [check the API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/):

> This function only works on plain JavaScript arrays of DOM elements, and is chiefly used internally by jQuery.

Comment: Is there any way to remove duplicates instead of writing own function??

Comment: @smsteel - jQuery doesn't have a function built-in for this no...that isn't it's purpose really, but a function isn't hard to write, see the question Pekka linked in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Console says:

```
> var data = "omg,lol,omg";
> $.unique(data.split(","))
["lol", "omg"]
```

However it is unreliable because it is meant to be used with DOM nodes. The sorting function that it uses is used to compare DOM nodes and is browser-specific. If you want to de-duplicate an array of strings, then the algorithm used by [`jQuery.unique`](http://github.com/jeresig/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L154-169) can be reused. Sort the array, and remove all consecutive matching elements.

```
function removeDuplicates(array) {
    array.sort();
    for(var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] == array[i-1]) {
            array.splice(i--, 1);
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```